# AdMobの広告を表示したいのですが、新規に登録した広告idでは広告が表示されません

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, admob

### 新規に広告IDを取得

```
//let TEST_ID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxx01/XXX001"  以前作成した広告ID
//let TEST_ID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxx02/XXX001"  今回作成した広告ID
//let TEST_ID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxx02/XXX002"  今回作成した広告ID
```

### 表示箇所

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    let TEST_ID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxx02/XXX002"
    var smartBannerView:GADBannerView = GADBannerView()
    smartBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
    let bHeight :CGFloat = 50 
    smartBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: self.view.frame.size.height-bHeight, width: self.view.frame.width, height: bHeight)
    smartBannerView.adUnitID = TEST_ID
    smartBannerView.rootViewController = self
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    smartBannerView.load(GADRequest())
    self.view.addSubview(smartBannerView)
}
```

### 結果

以前のIDでは表示されるのですが、今回作成したIDでは表示されません。
また以前作成した登録情報を見ようとしたのですが、ログインIDが違うのか確認できません。

Comment: まずはAdMobに対して問い合わせ・確認等を行ってみるべきではないでしょうか。

Comment: 以前のIDで表示されていたのは,テスト用の広告IDでした。新規IDの広告がいつから表示されるかわかりませんが、AdMobのHELPで　"最初の広告リクエストから掲載開始までに要する時間" という欄があり広告IDで表示されれば問題ないという事でした。

Comment: @user29507 さん、このご質問がオフトピック ("改善待ち") なのかどうか微妙なラインだなと感じたので、このサイトの使い方について質問できる「メタ」というサイトで質問してみました。ご参考までに。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2737/19110

Comment: 匿名ユーザーさんから編集の提案を頂いていますが、おそらく @user29507 さんご本人かと思います。ログインして頂ければご自身の質問は自由に編集ができ、またコメントもできますので、一度ログインして頂ければと思います。質問者さんご本人からの編集であると分からない限り、編集を承認しにくいのです。　／　自己解決した場合スタック・オーバーフローでは自己回答することができるのですが、質問が改善待ち状態になっているとこれができません。コメントで解決したこと（と、よろしければ解決法）をお知らせ頂ければ幸いです。お手数おかけして申し訳ありません。

Comment: 解決法 以前のIDで表示されていたのは,テスト用の広告IDでした。新規IDの広告がいつから表示されるかわかりませんが、AdMobのHELPで　"最初の広告リクエストから掲載開始までに要する時間" という欄があり広告IDで表示されれば問題ないという事でした。

Comment: 新規広告IDで表示されないので設定又は処理が間違っていると思っていたのですが、 AdMobのHELPで　"最初の広告リクエストから掲載開始までに要する時間" という欄がありテスト用の広告IDで表示されれば問題ないという事でした。以前のIDで表示されていたのはテスト用の広告IDでした

Comment: @user29507 さん、何度もお願いしてしまい申し訳ありません。ご質問が再オープンされました。したがって自己回答できるようになりましたので、よろしければお手すきの際コメント頂いた内容を回答に移して頂けると幸いです。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 解決法 以前のIDで表示されていたのは,テスト用の広告IDでした。新規IDの広告がいつから表示されるかわかりませんが、AdMobのHELPで　"最初の広告リクエストから掲載開始までに要する時間" という欄があり広告IDで表示されれば問題ないという事でした。

Answer (score 1):

コメントをまとめると、掲載開始までに時間がかかるというだけで、設定又は処理に間違はなかった、以前のIDはテスト用の広告IDで、それはAdMobの管理画面には表示されないということのようです。参考までに、AdMobのヘルプの記載は以下のとおりです。

> 最初の広告リクエストから掲載開始までに要する時間
>
> AdMob にアプリを新たに登録した場合、広告リクエストを何度かテストしてから広告枠を運用できるようになるため、実際の広告が掲載されるまでには多少の時間がかかります。
>
> アプリで広告リクエストが頻繁に発生するようになると、広告の掲載精度も高くなります。なお、テスト用広告も実際の広告と同じチャネルを通じて掲載されるので、テスト用広告が適切に返されれば、アプリと広告ネットワークが適切に連動していることになります。

なお、「まずはAdMobに対して問い合わせ・確認等を行ってみるべきではないでしょうか。」というコメントがありましたが、そのコメントは今回の質問に対しては適切なのですが、Googleのサポートは基本的にはサービスの障害とバグ対応で、アプリケーションへの組み込みは対象外であることに留意してください。

Comment: 「Googleのサポートは基本的にはサービスの障害とバグ対応で、アプリケーションへの組み込み」とありますが、今回のように発行されたIDが有効にならないのはサービスの障害なりバグなりと考えられるので、問い合わせを行ってみるべきではないでしょうか?現に問い合わせを行ったことですぐに状態が把握できたわけですし、「取得したIDがなぜ有効にならないのか」はまずはIDを管理する側で確認すべきように思われますが。

Comment: 回答をよく読んでください。コメントが適切でないと言っているわけではありません。ただ、Google等のサービスでは、問い合わせ・確認等だけで済むケースは少ないので、もう少し質問者に優しく対応してほしいので書いただけです。

Comment: 回答をよく読んだ上で、コメントが適切でないと言っているように読めたので、上のようにコメントさせていただきました。私としてはそのコメントが質問者に一番有益な情報だったことも踏まえ、あなたの表現の方が不適切に思えるのですが。

Comment: この質問は、有益な質問だと思うのですが、質問は一時クローズされるし回答の方は現在クローズされています。そのコメントは非常に適切なのですが、それで終わりにしてしまうところに問題があると思って書きました。

Comment: 私はクローズされたことそのものには問題なかったと考えていますが、お気持ちは十分わかります。ただ、そのコメント自体を「Googleへの質問の対象外ですよ」と言って切り捨ててしまうことは逆効果ではないかと思います。「問題がある」と思ったところをはっきり明示して書かれた方が良かったのではないでしょうか。もう一度クローズについての経緯なんて知らない人があなたの回答の「なお」の部分を読んだ時にどう読み取るか考えて見てください。